# Why are the bundle built using lodash and lodash-es in development mode very different in size?

Tags: node.js, webpack, lodash, webpack-5

**webpack.config.js**

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ title: 'production' })
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```js
import { join } from 'lodash';

const component = () => {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = join(['Hello', 'webpack'], ' ~ ');

    return element;
};

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

I first use the above configuration to bundle index.js in `production` mode.

When I use `lodash`, the size of the app.bundle.js is *70kb*. And when I use `lodash-es`, the size change to *219b*. I think it's because `lodash-es` supports Tree-Shaking.

But when I switch to `development` mode, the size of app.bundle.js using `lodash` is *554kb*. while using `lodash-es` the size is *5kb*.

What I already know is that Tree-Shaking is enabled by default in `production` mode, but not in `development` mode. I wonder what is causing the size difference between the `lodash` and `lodash-es` in `development` mode?

Answer (score 4):

This is because `lodash-es` package has been [marked as side-effect-free](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/#mark-the-file-as-side-effect-free)

> The new webpack 4 release expands on this capability with a way to provide hints to the compiler via the `"sideEffects"` `package.json` property to denote which files in your project are "pure" and therefore safe to prune if unused.

You will find `sideEffects` in [package.json](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.21-es/package.json#L14) of `lodash-es`.

```json
{
  "name": "lodash-es",
  "version": "4.17.21",
  "description": "Lodash exported as ES modules.",
  "keywords": "es6, modules, stdlib, util",
  "homepage": "https://lodash.com/custom-builds",
  "bugs": "https://github.com/lodash/lodash-cli/issues",
  "repository": "lodash/lodash",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "jsnext:main": "lodash.js",
  "main": "lodash.js",
  "module": "lodash.js",
  "sideEffects": false
}
```

> All the code noted above does not contain side effects, so we can mark the property as `false` to inform webpack that it can safely prune unused exports.

That's why when you `import { join } from 'lodash-es'`, other unused exports have been pruned even though the `mode` configuration is `'development'`.

As for `lodash` package, it's commonjs, not ESM, webpack can't do tree shaking for it.

E.g.

Let's create a `lib` and set the `sideEffects` to `false` in its `package.json`.

project structure:

```
$ tree -L 2 -I node_modules
.
├── lib
│   ├── a.js
│   ├── b.js
│   ├── index.js
│   └── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── index.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

`lib/a.js`:

```js
const a = () => 'a';

export default a;
```

`lib/b.js`:

```js
const b = () => 'b';

export default b;
```

`lib/index.js`:

```js
export { default as a } from './a';
export { default as b } from './b';
```

`lib/package.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "lib",
    "main": "index.js",
    "sideEffects": false
}
```

`src/index.js`:

```js
import { a } from '../lib';
console.log(a());
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        clean: true,
    },
};
```

Build logs:

```
> webpack

asset main.js 4.11 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
runtime modules 670 bytes 3 modules
orphan modules 112 bytes [orphan] 2 modules
cacheable modules 86 bytes
  ./src/index.js 46 bytes [built] [code generated]
  ./lib/a.js 40 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 78 ms
```

Output

`dist/main.js`:

```js
/******/    "use strict";
/******/    var __webpack_modules__ = ({

/***/ "./lib/a.js":
/*!******************!*\
  !*** ./lib/a.js ***!
  \******************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {\n/* harmony export */   \"default\": () => (__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__)\n/* harmony export */ });\nconst a = () => 'a';\n\n/* harmony default export */ const __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ = (a);\n\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./lib/a.js?");

/***/ }),

/***/ "./src/index.js":
/*!**********************!*\
  !*** ./src/index.js ***!
  \**********************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony import */ var _lib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ../lib */ \"./lib/a.js\");\n\nconsole.log((0,_lib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"default\"])());\n\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./src/index.js?");

/***/ })
```

If we remove the `sideEffects` field from `package.json`, let's see the output:

`dist/main.js`:

```js
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
/******/    var __webpack_modules__ = ({

/***/ "./lib/a.js":
/*!******************!*\
  !*** ./lib/a.js ***!
  \******************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {\n/* harmony export */   \"default\": () => (__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__)\n/* harmony export */ });\nconst a = () => 'a';\n\n/* harmony default export */ const __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ = (a);\n\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./lib/a.js?");

/***/ }),

/***/ "./lib/b.js":
/*!******************!*\
  !*** ./lib/b.js ***!
  \******************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {\n/* harmony export */   \"default\": () => (__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__)\n/* harmony export */ });\nconst b = () => 'b';\n\n/* harmony default export */ const __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ = (b);\n\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./lib/b.js?");

/***/ }),

/***/ "./lib/index.js":
/*!**********************!*\
  !*** ./lib/index.js ***!
  \**********************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {\n/* harmony export */   a: () => (/* reexport safe */ _a__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[\"default\"]),\n/* harmony export */   b: () => (/* reexport safe */ _b__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__[\"default\"])\n/* harmony export */ });\n/* harmony import */ var _a__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./a */ \"./lib/a.js\");\n/* harmony import */ var _b__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./b */ \"./lib/b.js\");\n\n\n\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./lib/index.js?");

/***/ }),

/***/ "./src/index.js":
/*!**********************!*\
  !*** ./src/index.js ***!
  \**********************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

eval("__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);\n/* harmony import */ var _lib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ../lib */ \"./lib/index.js\");\n\nconsole.log((0,_lib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.a)());\n\n\n//# sourceURL=webpack:///./src/index.js?");

/***/ })
```

As you can see, webpack does not prune the `lib/b.js` and `lib/index.js` files. They have been bundled in the `dist/main.js` file.